# Checking Entity Framework truncatetime againt SQL Server small datetime data type

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'm sure this is correct but I'm tracking down a bug. In the query below `widgetDate` is a `smallDateTime` data type. Is there anyway this code would step into "do stuff" if a record exists with today's date?

```
if (!_context.widgets.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.widgetDate) == DateTime.Today.Date))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This will be a poor performing query because as it's written it's not [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway this code would execute "do stuff" if a record already exists with today's date?